# How to fix bad DT_NEEDED location in Android 6

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a prebuilt library (**libprebuilt.so**) and my C program (**myprogram.c**) linked with the library.

I follow this tutorial (https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/prebuilts.html) and it works well in Android 5(API 22) device.

This is my **Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libprebuilt
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprebuilt.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := myprogram
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := myprogram.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libprebuilt
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Then I did **ndk-build** ,and rename folder libs to jniLibs.

This is my java program

```
try {
  System.loadLibrary("prebuilt");
  System.loadLibrary("myprogram");
} catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ule) {
  Log.e("Error", ule.getMessage());
}
```

However, when I test with Android 6 device, it does not work and give the following error.

```
dlopen failed: library "/my/build/machine/obj/local/armeabi/libprebuilt.so" not found
```

I found in the Android 6 Changes (https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html) that

> This release updates the behavior of the dynamic linker. The dynamic linker now understands the difference between a library’s soname and its path ( public bug 6670), and search by soname is now implemented. Apps which previously worked that have bad DT_NEEDED entries (usually absolute paths on the build machine’s file system) may fail when loaded.

So, the problem is that the DT_NEEDED entries are not located correctly, and the **myprogram** load **libprebuilt.so** in my local build machine path. What could I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Where did `libprebuilt.so` come from? This is https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/177

tl;dr, when `libprebuilt.so` was built, the ldflag `-soname libprebuilt.so` needed to be passed, but it wasn't.